# Preflight CORS request not working in Chrome 60

Tags: google-chrome, cors, preflight

I am having a small issue whereby Chrome (Version 60.0.3112.113, Mac OS) is returning a failed status response from a CORS preflight OPTIONS request.

The endpoint it is querying is a nodejs server which **previously** did not respond correctly to the preflight request. I have since fixed this.

The preflight request works in all other browsers, and works in Chrome on all other computers. I have tested using [Browserling](http://browserling.com), and everything works as expected.

As such I am assuming (with 99% confidence) that this is some sort of caching issue with Chrome on my development computer. I have however been unable to resolve this, and have at this point tried deleting any/all cache options that I can find in the various Chrome options menus.

Can anyone share any insight?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way of clearing whatever internal cache Chrome is using in this regard.

My resolution was simply to append a query string (based on the build time) to the request such that Chrome does not use this internal cache.

This is a good way of versioning resources (JS, CSS, API endpoints etc) anyway.